# Performing in command line what Xcode does when you run a build

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcodebuild

Is it possible to perform on the command line what Xcode does when you build and run against a iPhone which is hooked up through USB.

I am trying to automate the upload and install to iPhone process without using the play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tho I didn't try, it is almost certain you can do that.

Xcode is just a front-end of `xcodebuild` command line tool and other things.

Here's a link from Apple that will give you some basic info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_

To use the command, check here: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

See the `-destination` part.